# Android sdk for Intellij IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea, sdk, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I'm trying to setup IntelliJ IDEA to develop android applications and I faced an issue with android sdk. As far as I know, I need to download the sdk separately. But I all I managed to find was Android command line tools which is obviously not something I need. So my question how can I get android sdk for IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same problem I have with IDEA 2017.1.1. I installed tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip and [managed to install them](https://coolabccoder.wordpress.com/2017/04/19/android-in-intellij-idea-development-story/).
I've done:

1. unzipped it to C:\Android\android_sdk\
2. renamed "tools" folder to "tools-sdk"
3. executed 
   C:\Android\android_sdk\tools_inst\bin>sdkmanager --update
4. prepared file my_file with lines:

   build-tools;24.0.0

   platforms;android-24

   tools

   emulator
5. Executed:
   C:\Android\android_sdk\tools_inst\bin>sdkmanager --package_file=my_file

Then gave IntelliJ IDEA folder C:\Android\android_sdk as Android SDK Home Folder.

Then IDEA asks to install something additional. The test android project compiles and runs on emulation (AVD Manager works). I had to install 22 Platform and Build Tools though because android-24 virtual device asked for a password.

The only problem is I still have no SDK Manager with GUI interface.

Comment: Thanks for response. In fact Tools-sdk provides standard sdk manager GUI. Although I already managed to solve the issue. What you need is just launch sdk manager from the unzipped folder and install tools, atleast 2 API's and some extras. After that give IntelliJ IDEA path to sdk home folder and that's it. Sdk manager with gui can be launched from the IDEA as before.

Comment: Yes, I found it. SDK Manager GUI  starts from android.bat file in my C:\Android\android_sdk\tools_inst folder.

Answer (score 9):

You can install whichever android SDK or API from Intellij. I have the 2018.1 version but I hope this works in earlier versions too. You can find the options to install the SDKs here:[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you'be setup JDK properly. If not, you can download it from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
Now go to [Android Developer official site](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) and download Android Studio.

If you are already done with above mentioned points the few point you might be missing.

- When asked to choose the JDK (not SDK) you need to choose the Java JDK which you've installed earlier. Should be under C:\Program Files\Java\jdk{version}
- Choose a New platform ( if there's not one selected ) , the SDK platform is the android platform at C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows.

Please let me know if it didn't help.

**Reference:**
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/getting-started-with-android-development.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I tried downloading sdk via android eclipse setup process. Eclipse automatically downloads the sdk. This sdk has a gui sdkmanager and can be used in idea as well. Here is the [link](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) to download eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

(Android Studio installed on my computer.)
As i see users missed a point while installing android SDK.
You should show the Android SDK at AppData folder to IntellijIdea. 
C:\Users\Your_Username\AppData\Local\Android\SDK_Folder.
References: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/prerequisites-for-android-development.html
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/img/idea/2017.2/AndroidSDKManager.png

Answer (score -1):

You can download the android SDK from this link [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html). I hope it should be helpful that link.

Comment: Yes, but I can't find sdk installer on that link you provided. What should I do with android tools archive that can be downloaded from that link?