# Setting up Android SDK in IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, sdk

I am trying to set up JetBrains' IntelliJ IDEA for Android Development. I have "inherited" a relatively large Android project from one of my colleagues.

I am running into problems whenever I try to build the app in the IDE. I have tried to install the Android SDK into intelliJ but without any luck.

My problem seems to be that IntelliJ cannot locate the SDK correctly.

I have followed these steps, but with no result: 
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43501025/8156296)

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: Did you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45268592/104891)? I've verified that it works.

Comment: @CrazyCoder it's taking some time, i'll keep you posted if I get anywhere!

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have all the packages installed, but I cannot set "Build target" in IntelliJ...it just shows up as "[none]"... Thanks anyway, I'll figure it out soon!